# Bootstrap modal popup window in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I created a bootstrap pop-up window. when i click a button the pop up window is not get open .I tried to make a login form when click on a button the pop window need to be displayed with the username and password. But it is not working.

Comment: Please provide a sample code to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the bootstrap.min.js or bootstrap.js (for functionality) and bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css (for styling) and it's loading correctly.